# mysql filter null sum

Tags: mysql, null, sum

Minimal example

I have a `table1` with two columns (`id`, `name`)

```
1 asdf
2 fdsa
3 qwerty
4 ytrewq
```

I also have a `table2` with three columns (`id`, `ref`, `num`)

```
1 1 0.1
2 1 5.0
3 1 -3.9
4 2 2.4
5 2 -2.3
6 3 1.7
```

The following query:

```
SELECT
  table1.id,sum(num),
  table1.name as anumber
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.ref
GROUP BY table1.id;
```

gives me a result like:

```
1 1.2 asdf
2 0.1 fdsa
3 1.7 qwerty
4 NULL ytrewq
```

The query i tried:

```
SELECT
  table1.id,sum(num) as anumber,
  table1.name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.ref
GROUP BY table1.id
HAVING anumber is null or anumber >= 1.0;
```

My expectation is that I should see these results

```
1 1.2 asdf
3 1.7 qwerty
4 NULL ytrewq
```

But actually I get no results at all. How might I actually format my query here?

Ok so the query actually works as expected. I'm missing something from my actual setup that is making it not work.
The desired outcome is to find items that have a minimum value on a property specified by another table, or where that property is completely unknown.

Comment: `sum(num),table1.name as anumber` The alias is misplaced. You probably want `sum(num) as anumber, table1.name`

Comment: Hi. 1. Read a definition of left join and how group by works including what you are allowed to select after group by and how having works. Also read the manual re those things. Explain & justify why you think you should get that result. Look at intermediate results as you add those statements and explain & justify what you expect. 2. That info is good but please give a [mcve]. Besides making your code & data executable, seeking minimality would lead to you doing 1.

Comment: 3. You don't explain what you want your query to do. You expect us to guess from your example. Use language to say how in general output is a function of input. PS Don't you mean, sum(num) as anumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has the exact output that you want:

```
SELECT
  table1.id,sum(table2.num) as t2,
  table1.name as anumber
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.ref
GROUP BY table1.id
having t2 is null or t2 >= 1.0;
```

Output

```
id | t2 | anumber
1    1.2   asdf
3    1.7   qwerty
4    NULL  ytrewq
```